# Multibib, do NOT reset reference counter

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

Using the `multibib` package, I have two bibliographic sections.
I do not want the reference counter to be reset, which I had thought should be the default case. At least this is what the package documentation says, and reading the package code, the option `resetlabels` is off by default. But each bibliography starts counting from one.
Here comes a MWE (file mwe.tex):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{wwwbib}{Links to Webpages}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section*{Test multibib}
Reference to Buzz Lightyear \cite{ref01}.
The reference to Pixar I would expect to be number 2, but it is not \citewwwbib{ref02}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mwe}{}
\bibliographystylewwwbib{plainnat}
\bibliographywwwbib{mwe}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

To compile, I use

```
pdflatex mwe
bibtex mwe
bibtex wwwbib
pdflatex mwe
pdflatex mwe
```

The content of file `mwe.bib` is as follows:

```
@article{ref01,
   author = {Lightyear, Buzz},
   title = {To Infinity and Beyound Part 1},
   journal = {Unknown},
   volume = {54},
   number = {4},
   pages = {331-390},
   year = {2001}
}

@misc{ref02,
   author = {Pixar},
   title = {Pixar Website},
   howpublished = {\url{www.pixar.com}},
   year = {2001}
}
```

The pdf output is

[image]

How can I get continuous numbering?

Comment: Your example code produces the expected result on my system (TeX Live2013). Perhaps you are using outdated package(s)? Which LaTeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Compiles fine for me, too (MiKTeX 2.9).

Comment: 'Works for me' here: could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting `*File List*` into the question?

Comment: @Gonzola The problem was an outdated `multilib.sty`. Upgrading from version `2003/03/24 v1.2` to `2008/12/10 v1.4` worked.

Answer (score 2):

With my current MiKTeX 2.9 and `multibib`, version multibib 2008/12/10 v1.4 I get the following (wrong) file `wwwbib.aux`:

```
\citation{ref02}
\bibstyle{plainnat}
\bibdata{wwwbib}
\bibcite{ref02}{{2}{2001}{{Pixar}}{{}}},
```

Because there exists no file `wwwbib.bib` (line 3) reference `ref02` is invalid.  After changing `wwwbib` to `test` (the `bib` file is named `test.bib`) it worked.

The **reason** for this is that I usualy prefer to write an `filecontents` part like this to keep created `bib` or other file with the same name my MWE file has:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}                   % <==========
...
\end{filecontents*}
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}       % print here            % <==========
\bibliographystylewwwbib{plainnat}
\bibliographywwwbib{\jobname} % print here Online bib % <==========
```

If you use package `multibib`, this package uses itself macro `\jobname` to create file `wwwbib.aux` with `\jobname.aux` and `\bibdata{\jobname}` for the needed `\bibdata{test}`.

It seems that here is a bug in `multibib` (or in the system or `filecontents` for using `\jobname`, resulting in the wrong line `\bibdata{wwwbib}`  (instead of the correct `\bibdata{test}`).

**Solution:**
Do not use `\jobname` for `filecontents` if you need to use `multibib` in your MWE!

**Result**:

The following MWE runs without errors on my system:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}                  % <==========
@article{ref01,
  author  = {Lightyear, Buzz},
  title   = {To Infinity and Beyound Part 1},
  journal = {Unknown},
  volume  = {54},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {331--390},
  year    = {2001},
}
@misc{ref02,
   author       = {Pixar},
   title        = {Pixar Website},
   howpublished = {\url{www.pixar.com}},
   year         = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{wwwbib}{Links to Webpages}       


\begin{document}
\section*{Test multibib}
Reference to Buzz Lightyear \cite{ref01}.
The reference to Pixar I would expect to be number 2, 
but it is not \citewwwbib{ref02}.     

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}                     % <========== no \jobname here!
\bibliographystylewwwbib{plainnat}     
\bibliographywww{test}                  % <========== no \jobname here!

\end{document}
```

I got the wanted result:
[image]

Comment: With the same version of `multibib` in MiKTeX 2.9 I get the correct result.

Comment: Very strange, in my case `wwwbib.aux` contains `\bibdata{mwe}` since the first pdflatex run.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my `multibib.sty`, I found that I used version `2003/03/24 v1.2`.
Upgrading to version `2008/12/10 v1.4` did the trick.
v1.4 seems to have upgraded its support for the `natbib` package